# htaccess - change part of requested URL before sending user onwards?

Tags: html, .htaccess, lowercase

I have the following issue: we have an internal documentation system which generates help files as HTML. The software that generates them was recently upgraded and now there is a naming issue between capitalized and non capitalized folders.

Old URLs:

```
https://documentation.example.com/de/101/Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Components/Tablet.css
```

New URLs:

```
https://documentation.example.com/de/101/skins/default/stylesheets/components/tablet.css
```

We have different folders that are affected, so the URLs could look like this (there are many variations):

```
https://documentation.example.com/en/103/Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Components/Tablet.css
https://documentation.example.com/de/456/Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Components/Tablet.css
https://documentation.example.com/en/324/Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Components/Tablet.css
```

I would like to be able to take the requested URL, look for this string: "`/Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Components/Tablet.css`" change it to lowercase and then send the user on to the new changed URL.

Some of the solutions I have found require access to vhosts files which I don't. I am also unable to upload a PHP file or something like that.

Are there any solutions to my problem that could be done with the htaccess file alone? If yes how?

Comment: is it possible to provide your real url on comment?

Comment: It's within our network I'm afraid. I can't.

Comment: Does the URL always end with `/Skins/Default/Stylesheets/Components/Tablet.css`, or is that part variable as well?

Comment: Always ends like that.

Comment: "there are many variations" - How many variations? You only appear to give one specific example in your question. If the "variations" are made up of a finite number of words then you could rewrite each word individually. (?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) in your server/vhost config file where the css is hosted.

`RewriteMap lc int:tolower`

Then in your htaccess file, you can create a rule like:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${lc:$1} [L,NC]`

Let me know if you need anymore help. This htaccess rule will cause every url to be converted to lowercase. This is a generic htaccess you could make it more refined to search specifically for the URL you need.

Comment: And this rewrite map can only be added to the vhosts config file? Any way do this in the htaccess file?

Comment: No there isn't unfortunately. it has to be done in the apache config.

Comment: Thanks so much, how could I make this specific to that segment of the URL?

Comment: @ghoti change `[A-Z]` to something like Tablet.css to target specifically that file